# Use addView instead of a listView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to implement a code where there are multiple items.
I am able to populate the `ListView` and display all these items but I want to inflate a view `onItemClick`. Unfortunately, `AdapterView` does not support `addView()`.

So now I want to use `addView()` to dynamically add items by traversing an `ArrayList<>()`.
How do I do it?

Basically, I want to display a Custom Keypad layout next to a `TextView` inside the `ListView` and update the Value of the `TextView`

This is what I'm trying to do now.

```
public class OrderSummary extends Activity {
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_summary);
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.top_bar_layout, null);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.addView(view, params);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(OrderSummary.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add an item in your adapter and call notify the notifydatasetchanged method

Comment: i did that. the list IS getting populated but I cannot inflate another view on top of the listView. This is the problem I'm facing

Comment: have you tried with [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)? Much more convienient to use...

Comment: Yes I thought of RecyclerView but recycler view also uses the same adapter class, doesn't it? That will take me back to square one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is issue where are you adding linearLayout into main container ?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.order_summary); adds a nice big relative layout. The linearlayout is a child of that relativelayout

Comment: linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this); mean you are creating new

Comment: Oh yes. Now I understood! Thanks a ton

Comment: I used layout = (LinearLayout) findViewByID(id) instead of new LinearLayout(this);

Comment: It worked but now when I am adding more than one view it gives `IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root);

Comment: @YasirAli: Please consider editing your answer to include the code you have suggested in the comments, to make it a clearer answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is take a `LinearLayout`(with orientation set to vertical) instead of a `ListView`. Then make a custom view for each row, traverse the `ArrayList`, and then inflate the views and keep adding them to the `LinearLayout` with `addView()`.

P.S. without the actual code , I cannot tell you how to correct your code.

Comment: I suppose this is what you mean. but the view won't add. Should I pass some other value other than null for inflate()?